# Exporting a 2D array with 0-values into a txt/csv file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 100x100 array which I would like to export as either a txt or csv file. The elements of the array are all 0 and a few other integer numbers. When using the following code, the integer numbers are exported properly, but the zeros are replaced by random numbers with giganormous exponents (1.98E-258). Does anyone know a way to avoid this behavior?

The code that I am using is the following:

```
import numpy as np
my_array=np.ndarray(shape=(100,100))                                 
my_array[[],[]]=0  #WRONG
np.savetxt("my_file.csv", my_array, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: @pnuts -- OP wants the code to excel!  :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
my_array[[],[]]=0
```

replace it with

```
my_array[:,:]=0
```

The issue is that you're never really initializing the array, so everything is just random, including the exponents.  The above correction sets everything to zero.

Comment: That'll work too (although it'll be floats, not integers.)  I think using `np.zeros` is more idiomatic but it's important for the OP to learn the right assignment syntax too.

Comment: As others have said, if you really just want an array of zeros, and to export this to csv, then np.zeros is a better approach.  I assume you have bigger plans, and setting the values was the actual error in your code, so I focused on that, but if all you want is zeros, np.zeros will be more efficient, idiomatic, etc.  There are many ways to both initialize arrays and set ranges of values, and these are probably the two most important steps so it's worth reviewing multiple techniques for both.

Answer (score 4):

That's actually a really small number ... But what you need to do is tell numpy that the array will be filled with integers, not floats:

```
#or np.int32, np.int64, np.uint8 ... depending on desired range.
my_array=np.zeros((100,100), dtype=int)
```

While we're at it, I used `np.zeros` to give you an array initialized to zero since that seems to be what you want anyway.  Generally speaking, `np.ndarray` is used for subclassing a numpy array -- It's not very idiomatic to call the constructor yourself.

Comment: @DSM -- You're correct.  I wasn't paying close attention.  `OP` really should be using `np.zeros` if he/she wants an array to fill with zeros.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had forgotten about np.zeros!! This version or the one above (tom10) both work. Thanks for your explanations. Needless to say...I am a newbie!